# How to access local variable from another function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nameerror

What is wrong with this code?

```
def function1():
        num1 = input("enter a number")
        num1 != num2:
            print("Access")
        else:
            print("Error")
    def function2():
        num2 = input("enter number")
        if num2 != num1:
            print("Access")
        else:
            print("Error")
```

```
  if num1 != num2:
NameError: name 'num2' is not defined
```

Comment: Hello, you're probably overlooking the term _local_ variable! In this case, local means it's local to the function. If you want to access the variable in both functions you can either pass the variable into the function as a parameter, or make the variables global (hopefully the former).

Comment: Your first if statement has a syntax error. It says num1 != num2: and it should say if num1 != num2:

Answer (score 2):

This is the easiest way.

```
def function1():
    global num1
    num1 = input("enter a number")


def function2():
    global num2
    num2 = input("enter number")


function1()
function2()


if num2 != num1:
    print("Access")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Does not works ..  The value of num1 and num2 will be None ..

Comment: After you run the code, you will have to input the numbers first.

Comment: it will print("Error") only ... 
`enter a number2
enter number7
None
None
Error`
The value will remain None

Comment: Do ```int(input("enter a number"))``` inside both the functions

Answer (score 1):

Use keyword `global` to make local varaible accesible globally. Like:-

```
def function1():
    global num1
    num1 = input("enter a number")
       
def function2():
    global num2 
    num2 = input("enter number")
```

*Note:- It won't work when you call the function, because when first function is called, you haven't called function2() so, will show nameError. Main goal of the answer is to introduce you `global` keyword.

## EDIT

```
def function1():
    return input("enter a number")

def function2():
    return input("enter number")

num1 = function1()
num2 = function2()

if num2 != num1:
    print("Access")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: i want to compare between num1 and num2 ................


`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tictac.py", line 69, in <module>
    function1()
  File "tictac.py", line 56, in function1
    if num1 != num2:
NameError: name 'num2' is not defined`

Comment: This just way to show you how to access local varaible. As, your function is not correct it won't work because, as you call first function, another function's second value is not stored, so will cause error. I wanted you to know about ```global``` keyword. Other things, try working with as much function as you can, there are several ways to do what you are askin. See, Kunal Sikri answer, that would work!!!